# Can I successfully self-petition with an EB-2 visa to the US?

Tags: usa, working-visas, immigration

I am currently looking at self-petitioning for an EB-2 visa under Advanced Degree. I have worked in the Telecommunications sector in the UK for almost 6 years with a STEM degree as a data scientist focussed on ML applied research with one peer reviewed publication, a number of patents and few presentations at conferences and white papers in industry journals. I recently completed my MSc (as of 2022) in DS and would like to self-petition for an EB-2 visa by filing an I-400 with National Interest Waiver.  Is this a viable option for someone of a similar background?

EDIT: I was wondering whether something like a general advancing the field of AI/ML research would be a good enough basis without extensive research record.

Comment: What's the basis for the NIW?

Comment: I would get a US Immigration lawyer and check with them if that is even a possibility

Comment: @NicolasFormichella it's certainly a possibility, as anyone can tell from a quick look at relevant US law and information from USCIS (https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-second-preference-eb-2)  The question is whether it's a _realistic_ possibility in Sk88's case, and a lawyer ought to be able to shed some light on that. But wise clients will want to have some idea for themselves so they can be wary of the possibility of an unscrupulous lawyer agreeing to take their money when a refusal is likely.

Comment: @phoog I would recommend staying away from lawyers taking their money when a refusal occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a viable option for someone of a similar background?

Many immigration businesses focusing on greening immigrants will give you an evaluation for free. In case they think you are highly likely to get approved for NIW, they will make you pay the lawyer fees only if the NIW is approved. (Note that in case of a reject, you'll still have to pay the USCIS fees). Therefore I'd recommend that you ask one or several such immigration businesses. I personally only have experience with PhD applicants, not MS, so I can't comment on your case specifically.